# Which KDF should be used for ECIES?

Tags: pbkdf2, ecies

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme), ECIES requires a key derivation function.
I already have an implementation of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 in my library, so I could use this.

Is PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 (salted of course) sufficient as KDF? Or should I use another KDF?

Comment: You could use unsalted PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 with a single iteration. Personally I'd rather use HKDF or even a plain hash.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I would prefer KDF1 or KDF2 for the simple reason that you can claim you used an actual KDF. It's not much more than a hash anyway - creating & including a 4 byte counter is not *that* much work. Makes it easier to derive more keys later too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you do that? It's the ***Password-Based*** Key Derivation Function 2, and ECIES doesn't work with a password but with a DH shared secret, thus not suffering from the same issues that plague passwords (such as low entropy-density).

Not to say it wouldn't suffice, but if you need something a straight hash or HMAC doesn't provide, KDF1 and KDF2 are your friends.

Comment: A HMAC has two input parameters and a statically sized output. You would need to use the secret as key and then keep the leftmost bits. The input may be anything, a counter, key identifier or even empty.

Comment: That was a braino (just fixed it), I meant a hash.